# Why are there two of the same program in my applications?

Tags: appmenu

I updated my Joplin notes program and instead of replacing the old version, a new one (right) was installed. Why did this happen? How do I remove the old version?

[image]

Comment: You've installed the snap version as well as the APT version

Comment: Yes it does thank you!